# Alternative to Falsely Triggering an Event

Tags: javascript, data-binding

**TLDR Below**
[JS Fiddle To Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/t1aq4596/5/)

I've been really involved in recreating the tools that are foundations of premiere JS Libraries to better improve my skills. Currently I'm working on functional data-binding a la Angular.

The idea of data-binding is to take data and bind it to elements so that if manipulated all elements subscribed will change accordingly. I've gotten it to work but one thing I hadn't considered going into it was the issue with innerHTML vs value. Depending on the element you need to change one or the other( in the demo above you'll see that I needed to specifically single out the button element in a conditional statement because it has both, but that's kind of a fringe case )

The issue is that in order to capture a SPAN tag update I needed to trigger an event to happen, and the easiest one to manipulate for Text Boxes/Textareas was 'keyup'.

In my function then, if you pass in an element with no value property we assume you're going to be updating innerHTML, and we setup an observer to determine if the element ever mutates, and if it ever does, the observer will emit a 'keyup' event.

```
  if (watchee.value == void(0)) {
var keyUpEvent = new Event('keyup');
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    watchee.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);
  });
});
observer.observe(watchee, {
  childList: true
});
}
```

Now it may just be my paranoia, but it seems like I might be tunneling into a can of worms by faking 'keyup' on an element that doesn't natively have that support.

**TLDR:**

I'm curious if there's an alternative way to make, a.e. a span tag reactive other than faking a 'keyup'/'keydown'/'change' event? For instance, is there a way that I can make my own pure event(by pure I mean not reliant on other events) that checks if innerHTML or value has changed and then performs a function? I know that this is probably possible with a timer, but I feel like that might hinder performance.

**EDIT**: just an aside. In the demo the function called hookFrom works by taking a DOM node and returning a function that will take the receiving dom node and continues to return a function that will take additional receiving dom nodes. :

```
hookFrom(sender)(receiver);
hookFrom(sender)(receiver)(receiver2);
hookFrom(sender)(receiver)(receiver2)(receiver3)(receiver4)...(receiver999)...etc
```

[JS Fiddle To Demo (same as above)](https://jsfiddle.net/t1aq4596/5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing inherently wrong with creating a similar event on a DOM node that doesn't natively have that functionality. In fact this happens in a lot of cases when trying to polyfill functionality for separate browsers and platforms.

The only issue with doing this sort of DOM magic is that it can cause redundancy in other events. For instance the example given in this article: https://davidwalsh.name/dont-trigger-real-event-names shows how a newly minted event using the same event name can cause problems.

The advice is useful, but negligible in this specific case. The code adds the same functionality between text boxes, divs, spans, etc... and they are all intentionally handled the same way, and if the event *would* bubble up to another event, it would be intentional and planned.

In short: There is a can of worms that one can tunnel into while faking already explicitly defined event names, but in this case, the code is fine!